# Problem with using node.js on VSC with Windows

Tags: node.js

My laptop is 64-bit operating system, Windows 10
I have installed Node.js for Windows (version v12.17.0) 
I have installed code.runner on VSC as well

However, the error msg 
"Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs"

keep appearing. I have no idea what is wrong.

Will changing the user settings or workspace settings help ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not set the Path in the Environment Variables. 
In Windows, search for "Environment Variables".

Open **Environment Variables**.Open Path and add the PATH : **C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin**

*By default, the installer uses the Node.js distribution in **C:\Program Files\nodejs**. If node is installed in  **C:\Program Files\nodejs** directory, then add the PATH in  in window's PATH environment variable as **C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin**.*

Restart any open command prompts for the change to take effect.